# SQL: Extract a string from between the 2nd and 3rd dashes (-), if they exist. Else N/A

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to write SQL to extract the string from the 2nd and 3rd dashes on the "Campaign" column to a new column "Language".

If no 2nd and 3rd dashes, then "N/A". Thank you for your help!

| Campaign | Language |
| --- | --- |
| na--en-abc | en |
| na-branded | N/A |
| ap--jp-xyz | jp |
| eu-uk-en-jjj | en |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple approach

```
select Campaign,
  ifnull(split(Campaign, '-')[safe_offset(2)], 'N/A') as Language
from your_table
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Mikhail! It works.